# How to create these sorts of textures?

Tags: texture

:))

I've always wondered how to recreate some textures I always adored these scanlines, 'gritty, badly scanned' grainy effect on a pic?

Would be mega helpful if you knew[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy receipe for Photoshop:

Fill a new layer with solid 50% grey. Have so big canvas size in pixels that you can fit the needed photo rectangle even in case you must rotate the image to change the direction of the forthcoming lines.

Apply Filter> Sketch > Halftone Pattern > Lines to the grey layer. My ancient Photohop makes only horizontal lines, but I can rotate the image after making the lines. The next image is a zoomed screenshot:

[image]

Rotate the image to the wanted position of the lines, place or drag from another open image the wanted photo below the grey lines layer. Let the lines have blending mode Multiply or Hard light and reduce their layer opacity to get a subtle texture:

[image]

I have rotated the image 90 degrees before inserting the photo. The lines layer has Opacity =25% and blending mode = Multiply. The "fake painting" -like filtering is in the photo, it isn't a part of the effect.

Comment: thank you so so much‼️ I wish I could reply and upvote but my reputation is slightly below levels lol ;)